# How to determine shape of .pth file in google colab

Tags: python, model, google-colaboratory, shapes, dimension

I have **abc.pth** file which is a feature file. I want to determine the shape/dimension of this file through google colab. how to load it and determine its shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> path="/path/to/abc.pth"
>
> import torch a=torch.load(path) a.size()

and it will output the tensor

> torch.Size([1, 2048, 19, 29])